# How to set minimum and maximum time for a progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I have designed a progress bar, it will be in a box with black background, then it works till the page is loaded. Then the div fades out and the actual website appears.
But the progress bar must follow two rules:

- Firstly it must work till the page is completely loaded. (I was suggested to use `$(".page").remove();` for this, is that correct?)
- Secondly the progress bar must have a minimum and maximum time to load. So it takes at least 5 seconds to load and maximum 10 seconds.

So I have created the progress bar with the style but the js part does not follow the above rules.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qCCzE/9/)**
Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
    <div class="progress-label">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-progressbar-value {
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/b/bb/SoundCloud_logo.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    background-size: 300px 200px;
    border: 0px;
    -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
}
.ui-progressbar {
    width: 300px;
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/b/bb/SoundCloud_logo.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 0;
}
.ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {
    margin: 0;
}
.progress-label {
    font-size: 90px;
    color: white
}
.page {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var progressbar = $("#progressbar"),
        progressLabel = $(".progress-label");

    progressbar.progressbar({
        value: false,
        change: function() {
            progressLabel.text(progressbar.progressbar("value") + "%");
        },
        complete: function() {
            progressLabel.text("Done!");
            $(".page").fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });

    function progress() {
        var val = progressbar.progressbar("value") || 0;

        progressbar.progressbar("value", val + 1);

        if (val < 99) {
            setTimeout(progress, 100);
        }

    }

    setTimeout(progress, 1000);
});
```

I am really new to jQuery and do not know how to fulfill the two above mentioned rules at the same time.

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: @Bergi Erm, the page will not be empty obviously, there is a progress bar that is working and showing something is happening.

Comment: @dandavis well thats why i want it to work when the page is completely loaded. But there is a case that some user might load the pade in 1 sec. So in that case it would take 5 secs at least just to have a normal behavior. And for those users that might take over 10sec, then it must stop it and load the page even if the bg is not completed yet. So I believe it is half real progress and half fake one.

Comment: @CBroe well it might be nonsense to you as u have no idea about the whole project, and in fact your comment is non sense as it does not contain anything constructive.